# RSpecのdescribeをFactoryGirlで作ったデータで回したい

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

下記のように`each`を使ってほとんど重複するテストを共通化しようとしています。

```
RSpec.describe Hoge, type: :model do
  describe 'describe1' do
    [create(:foo), create(:bar)].each do |v|
      describe "#{v.name}" do
        # vを使ってテスト
      end
    end
  end
end
```

この場合、下記のようなエラーになりうまくいきません。

```
from /Users/shingo/Documents/raku/project/spec/models/hoge_spec.rb:53:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
from /Users/shingo/Documents/raku/project/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.4.4/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:385:in `module_exec'
from /Users/shingo/Documents/raku/project/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.4.4/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:385:in `subclass'
from /Users/shingo/Documents/raku/project/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.4.4/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:255:in `block in define_example_group_method'
from /Users/shingo/Documents/raku/project/spec/models/hoge_spec.rb:36:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
from /Users/shingo/Documents/raku/project/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.4.4/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:385:in `module_exec'
from /Users/shingo/Documents/raku/project/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.4.4/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:385:in `subclass'
from /Users/shingo/Documents/raku/project/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.4.4/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:255:in `block in define_example_group_method'
from /Users/shingo/Documents/raku/project/spec/models/hoge_spec.rb:35:in `block in <top (required)>'
from /Users/shingo/Documents/raku/project/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.4.4/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:385:in `module_exec'
from /Users/shingo/Documents/raku/project/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.4.4/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:385:in `subclass'
from /Users/shingo/Documents/raku/project/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.4.4/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:255:in `block in define_example_group_method'
from /Users/shingo/Documents/raku/project/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.4.4/lib/rspec/core/dsl.rb:43:in `block in expose_example_group_alias'
from /Users/shingo/Documents/raku/project/spec/models/hoge_spec.rb:26:in `<top (required)>'
```

どのようにすれば、`each`で共通化できるのでしょうか？

Comment: `describe "#{v.name}"`の後ろに`do`がありませんがtypoでしょうか?

Comment: 質問するために、変数名等いじったので、そのときに消してしまったようです。修正しました。

Comment: エラー内容が書かれているのですが、これはスタックトレースのみで肝心の何がエラーになったのかが出てないように思うのですがいかがでしょうか。見方を間違っていたらすみません。

Comment: バックトレースのみで肝心のエラーは表示されてないです。最終的な結論としてRSpec的にここにはcreateを書けないように思いました。

Answer (score 1):

it を書き忘れていたりしないでしょうか？ なお、each を使う方法にはなっていませんが、共通化するなら、shared_examples や shared_context を使のが良いと思います。

[RSpec の入門とその一歩先へ、第2イテレーション ～RSpec 3バージョン～ - Qiita](http://qiita.com/jnchito/items/47f539ddca7dbc01acef#shared_examples-%E3%82%92%E4%BD%BF%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A6%E3%83%86%E3%82%B9%E3%83%88%E3%81%AE%E9%87%8D%E8%A4%87%E3%82%92%E6%8E%92%E9%99%A4%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B)

今回のケースなら、下記のような感じでしょうか。

```
RSpec.describe Hoge, type: :model do
  shared_examples "describe1" do
    it do 
      # vを使ってテスト
    end
  end

  context "foo" do
    let(:v)  { create :foo }
    it_behaves_like 'describe1'
  end

  context "bar" do
    let(:v)  { create :bar }
    it_behaves_like 'describe1'
  end
end
```